Will Chain link price changes will affect hash value?
If I fetched the current USD price from Chainlink, deployed my contract, and new blocks were mined after that, what happens if the USD price changes? Will the hash of the contract or the  blocks after it change?

The contract address or anything related to the contract's bytecode won't change due to the change in price, obviously.
By accessing a price feed, you're just storing the corresponding value in some storage variable inside the contract. It would just change the value of that variable depending on the change in price; it doesn't have anything to do with the contract's bytecode, address, transaction hashes, blocks, etc.
